# Finding residue of double pole

Tags: integration, residue-calculus, complex-integration

I'm trying to find the residue of the pole $+ib$ of $$f(z) = \frac{e^{iaz}}{(z^2+b^2)^2}$$

(the pole $-ib$ lies outside of the contour).

I'm trying to do this by $$Residue = (\frac{e^{iaz}}{(z^4+2z^2b^2+b^4)'})_{ib} = (\frac{e^{iaz}}{4z^3+4zb^2)})_{ib} = \frac{e^{ia(ib)}}{4(ib)^3+4(ib)b^2}$$

But the denominator still disappears. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the residue of $f(z)/z^2$ at $z = 0$ where $f$ is holomorphic ? (the residue is the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ in the Laurent series)

Comment: @user1952009 I get $\frac{1}{2(ib)-2ib}$ which I know is wrong as it disappears :(

Comment: so the answer to my question was $f'(0)$, not $f(0)$

Comment: @user1952009 sorry, I don't understand

Comment: when $f$ is holomorphic, $Res(f(z)/z^2,0) = f'(0)$ . now adapt this to your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's demonstrate how to find the residue at the pole $z=i b$ by the definition of a residue, i.e., by finding the coefficient of the $(z-i b)^{-1}$ term in the Laurent expansion of $f(z)$.  To do this, define $\zeta=z-i b$; then $f(z)$ may be written as

$$f(\zeta+i b) = \frac{e^{i a (\zeta+i b)}}{[(\zeta+i b)^2+b^2]^2} = \frac{e^{-a b}}{(i 2 b \zeta)^2} \frac{e^{i a \zeta}}{\left ( 1+\frac{\zeta}{i 2 b} \right )^2} $$

As you can see, we have a first term in $\zeta^{-2}$, so we seek the coefficient of $\zeta$ in the expansion of the second term.  This expansion is

$$ -\frac{e^{-a b}}{(2 b \zeta)^2} (1+i a \zeta+\cdots) \left ( 1 - 2 \frac{\zeta}{i 2 b} + \cdots\right )$$

so that the coefficient of $\zeta$, and thus the residue is

$$ -i \frac{e^{-a b}}{4 b^2} \left ( a + \frac1{b}\right ) $$